# Library function not working: Uncaught at saveData

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, modal-dialog

So, I got to build a script that asks the user for some information using google apps script. Those codes must be in a specific spreadsheet (1st URL), so does the HTML form that will be loaded by a modal dialog.

Even though the code is written in the spreadsheet **SCRIPTS**, that project is loaded as a library on the project from spreadsheet **workbook**, and that's the spreadsheet that will create a menu that will load the code from **SCRIPTS**.

The final goal is: the user opens **workbook**, runs the item from `MyMenu > Form`, a modal/form is opened; the user writes his info and hits **submit**. After that, the function `saveData` from **SCRIPTS**, which will write the informations in the spreadsheet **requests**.

Obs.: since `saveData` needs to call 2 methods hosted in the **SCRIPTS** project, it also needs to be hosted in the same project.

SCRIPTS: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dkntw25H41JTk0R3Rm9fgiwt_RrAee9zYEz1Wy8DomI/edit?usp=sharing
requests: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o8JbVelmSNoGn6sn7laatBam_2WTtToB_nlZMTFY_Rg/edit?usp=sharing
workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17plSc9-kPj6XMBENBLJEE6sc01i82xfhGGPQ1UmOXjE/edit?usp=sharing

The problem here is that on the spreadsheets I shared above, everything works flawlessly, but on the original spreadsheets I need to work on (there are sensitive data from my job there, I can't share the url), when I click on the button `submit`, I only get this error on the console and nothing works:

**PS.: Although I can't share my job's spreadsheet, all the code, from the one in the workbook to the one in the scripts spreadsheet are exactly the same as I wrote for my job, using different spreadsheets just like I said here, and still I get the error below:**

[image: original-error]

Some code that might be helpful for you:

Project: **workbook**

```js
// Code.gs

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('MyMenu').addItem('Form', 'closeKits').addToUi();
}
```

```js
// CloseKits.gs

function closeKits() {
  scripts.showForm();
}

function callLibraryFunction(data){
  scripts.saveData(data);
}
```

**appsscript.json**

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "scripts",
        "version": "0",
        "libraryId": "1AhbUglj05OrQuaZFqQcL_0UB7MCGope2YpVnE7eOGYjdxiXug0DiDA1i",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

**Project SCRIPTS:**

```html
<!-- Form.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="requestedBy">Requested By</label>
            <input id="requestedBy" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="validate">
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <label for="dueDate">Due Date</label>
            <input id="dueDate" class="datepicker">
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea id="comments" placeholder="Please ignore lines X, Y and Z..." class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var options = {
          autoClose: true,
          format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          setDefaultDate: true,
          showClearBtn: true
        };

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
          var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elements, options);
        });

        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', getData);

        function getData() {
          var requestedBy = document.getElementById('requestedBy').value;
          var dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate').value;
          var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value;

          var data = {
            requestedBy: requestedBy,
            dueDate: dueDate,
            comments: comments
          };
          
          google.script.run.callLibraryFunction(data);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here I had to use that `callLibraryFunction` present in the `Code.gs` from **workbook** in order to call the library function `saveData`, since that last method is not visible to the HTML client running on **workbook**.

```js
// SaveData.gs

function saveData(data) {
  const iasRequestsSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1o8JbVelmSNoGn6sn7laatBam_2WTtToB_nlZMTFY_Rg');
  const sheet = iasRequestsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('page1');

  const line = getFirstEmptyRow(sheet);

  // requested by
  sheet.getRange(line, 2).setValue(data.requestedBy);

  // due date
  sheet.getRange(line, 6).setValue(data.dueDate);

  // comments
  sheet.getRange(line, 9).setValue(data.comments);
}
```

```js
// ShowForm.gs

function showForm() {
  const form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form').evaluate().setHeight(480);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(form, 'Form');
}
```

```js
// GetFirstEmptyRow.gs

function getFirstEmptyRow(sheet) {
  const column = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = column.getValues();

  let row = 0;

  for (row; row<values.length; row++) {
    if (!values[row].join("")) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return (row+1);
}
```

Please feel free to ask any other information in order to solve this, and also access those spreadsheets and run once the `onOpen` from **workbook**, so it requests the required permissions to you.

**EDIT:**
As asked, after clicking `submit`, on the spreadsheet `workbook` I get only this in the logs:

[image: exec logs]

Comment: @Rubén I have just updated the question, it was kinda wrong before, now it is correct: the exact same code distributed identically on my job and the spreadsheets I shared here works only with the spreadsheets I shared here, but on my job I get that error mentioned above.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the Apps Script side? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Hey @ale13 I have updated the original question with a screenshot from my execution logs right after running the menu form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it was something with the browser... On my job notebook it worked using the edge, and for my colleagues it worked both on chrome and edge. But I still don't know what is the incompatibility here.